# Name of the LU decomposition algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

On the wikipedia page of [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) there is an algorithm that produce the decomposition. It is called [Doolittle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Doolittle_algorithm).

I'm really interested who is Doolittle? Or from where the name comes from? Is there any citation for the original work of the algorithm? As I know the decomposition is invented be Alan Turing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference to the Doolittle's paper is missing on Wiki:

Doolittle, M.H.: Method employed in the solution of normal equations and the adjustment of a triangularization. In: U. S. Coast and Geodetic Survey, Report, pp. 115–120 (1878).

For more information, see [Mathematicians of Gaussian Elimination](http://www.ams.org/notices/201106/rtx110600782p.pdf) by Grcar. Apparently, Doolittle worked as a computer.